# How does an oracle contract get data from outside the blockchain?

Tags: smart-contracts, oracle

I want to build an oracle which gets data on chain from a weather API.

The way I'm thinking about implementing this is to run a server which periodically fetches the data from a weather API, and calls an "%update_data" entrypoint with the data on the oracle contract (this entrypoint can only be called by the admin).

Is this how oracles usually built?

Doesn't this centralise the data?

What would be a better approach?